# BSC Testnet and ETH Testnet, I want to copy/fork a contract in eth which is evermoon, but I always get an error with the gas and it always fails

Tags: solidity, gas, error, bsc, cpp-ethereum

This is the error it gives me, can you help me fix this problem, I adjust the gas limit, it started from 3000000, to 30000000, but still the transaction failed. I tried in bsc testnet using pancakeswap testnet router, and also in eth with uniswap testnet router. but still failing.

This is the error.

Gas Estimation Failed.
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"execution reverted","id":5440917588647472}

Comment: I have testbnb from faucet and also sepolia test eth. so no problem with the amount in of test tokens in my wallet.

Comment: That's a generic error. You can try force sending and copying the transaction hash here so we can have a better look.